# How to Export SQL Query to TXT Using Command Line

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

I want to export `select * from table` results to a text file from the command line in linux. How should I do this?

Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 18, accepted):

look at [link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)

you only need to add this to the query

```
select * from table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfilename.txt'
```

you can improve this to csv file (using it in excel latter)

like :

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfilename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```